# Chess game, Changing the object being iterated on.

Tags: ruby

This is my method that is supposed to check for a check mate. One part of it is not working correctly. While @board[][] = element works when I try to change "element" which is the element being iterated on to a string, nothing happens. It stays whatever object it was. Is it not possible to change an element being iterated on with .each ?

```
@board[move[0]][move[1]] = element 
element = " "
```

@board is an array of arrays, filled with strings and chess piece objects. If check is true the method is supposed to iterate through every pieces possible moves to see if any break the check.

```
  def check_mate(color) 
    @board.each do |row|
      row.each do |element|
        if element == " "
        elsif element.color != color 
          elsif element.possible_moves(@board).each do |move|
            if check(color) == true
              save_game
              @board[move[0]][move[1]] = element 
              element = " "
              display
              if check(color) == true 
                load_game
              elsif check(color) != true 
                return true 
                break
              end
            else return true   
            end 
          end
        end
      end
    end   
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are modifying `element` which is a local copy of the object in row[]. I think you want to modify row[]. You can use `each_with_index` instead of `each` when iterating through the row:

```
row.each_with_index do |element, index|
```

and then modify the element in the row:

```
row[index] = " "
```